# Full internet connectivity but ping fails

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, ping

Using Windows 8.1 Professional with a USB wireless adapter(TP-LINK Archer T4U), I have full internet connectivity yet all ping calls fail with "Request timed out". Onboard Wifi is disabled at the moment.

List of network adapters:
Cisco AnyConnect Mobility Adapter
VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Bluetooth Network Connection
WiFi (onboard)
WiFi 2 (The TP-LINK Archer T4U)

I have no idea what's going on, output of ipconfig is provided.

```
C:\Users\Neil>ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : user.wls.ucf.edu
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::920:8b16:87ec:26b2%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.32.150.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.192.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.32.128.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5564:3899:34af:89c7%32
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.user.wls.ucf.edu:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : user.wls.ucf.edu

Tunnel adapter isatap.{EF3A2B1C-B9C3-4304-B2E1-BA6D52C3186B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that PING (or ICMP) packets are blocked/dropped on that network.

Comment: Sounds like a possible reason. I'll try on another network and check back in.

Comment: @Dar13 You could simply ask the IT helpdesk. I’m sure they’ll have info on something as basic as that.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is a problem of ICMP which I had it before, So CHECK:
http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7
https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy

Comment: And if I don't know what to search in Google? I have enabled the firewalls that allow incoming/outgoing ping requests for IPv4/v6 and the problem persists.